# leafletjs custom map with a single image png file showing multiple maps

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I have a single image file and i am using leafletjs module to try to zoom on it, however when executing the code it's showing multiples times the same image. Did try to use the noWrap option to true but nothing happen.
Any idea how can i do this ?

```
<script text="text/javascript">
var map = L.map('map', {
        maxZoom: 24,
        minZoom: 1,
        noWrap: true,
        crs: L.CRS.Simple
    }).setView([0, 0], 5);

    map.setMaxBounds(new L.LatLngBounds([0,2048], [2048,0]));

L.tileLayer('maps/map.png').addTo(map);
</script>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Found it why...

I need to use the imageOverlay instead of the tileLayer one ...
https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.4.html#imageoverlay

```
<script text="text/javascript">

var map = L.map('map', {
    minZoom: 1,
    maxZoom: 3,
    center: [0, 0],
    zoom: 1,
    crs: L.CRS.Simple
});
var w = 2048;
var h = 2048;
var url = 'maps/map_b_final.png';
var southWest = map.unproject([ 0, h], map.getMaxZoom()-1);
var northEast = map.unproject([ w, 0], map.getMaxZoom()-1);
var bounds = new L.LatLngBounds( southWest, northEast);

L.imageOverlay( url, bounds).addTo(map);

map.setMaxBounds(bounds);
</script>
```